# Impressão com orientação errada do Jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports

Tenho a impressão de um pequeno recibo na orientação retrato que fiz no Jasper Studio, porém ao imprimi-lo, ele aparece na orientação paisagem. Por algum motivo os leitores de PDF não respeitam a orientação, e com certeza, deve ser alguma coisa que estou fazendo errado.
Como faço para fixar a impressão dele como retrato?

Tentei colocar o código aqui mas é muito grande, então no link a seguir, seque o .jrxm que desenvolvi.

[recibo.jrxml](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuzrEJzwNWacuz9CbfNGZzi6wXva)

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar o problema, criei um relatório do tamanho da página A4, adicionei a ele um sub-report com o tamanho da impressão desejada, com isso, o sistema imprimiu o recibo na orientação retrato do jeito que eu queria.

Não sei se essa é a melhor forma, mas funcionou!